# Show content in round brackets with regex

Tags: regex

I have the following string:

ABC (123)

Now with the help of regex, I just want to have the "123" - the content in the round brackets.

I used `\(.*?\)` - but here the round brackets still appear. How can I additionally remove the round brackets / or just show the content inside?

Comment: `\([^()]*\)` ... (It's good to specify programming language flavour)

Comment: Thanks, but this one still includes the brackets. I need it for a google sheets formula.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you trying to use REGEXEXTRACT? Have you tried using REGEXREPLACE twice?

```
REGEXREPLACE("ABC (123)", "[^\(]*\(", "")
REGEXREPLACE("123)", "\)", "")
```

Or you could use REGEXEXTRACT twice.

```
REGEXEXTRACT("ABC (123)", "\(.*\)")
REGEXEXTRACT("(123)", "[^\(\)]")
```

Comment: #1 works, #2 just leaves a "1" at the end - but #1 is working. thank you